# iOS creating a multi column table/grid

Tags: ios, cocoa

I am looking to show a schedule like the week view of the calendar app for iPad, but zoomable and scrollable(2-D). I'm not really sure where to start with this. 
The Data structure would look something like this:

- |Time|Stage A|Stage B|Stage etc...|
- |8:00|
- |9:00|
- etc...

With an unknown number of stages and times and the header and sidebar fixed in the view and always visible (they would zoom in when someone zooms of course.) 
I originally thought a bunch of UITableViews next to each other in a UIScrollView, but with an unknown sized "grid", this wouldn't exactly work.  But I still think that a bunch of UITableViews is the way to go.

I've looked at a bunch of grid view libraries, but they only make grids of units the same size, not different heights, plus a lot of them are quite buggy.

I would like to hear some suggestions on how I should proceed.

A good example of what I am looking for with the header is this html example: [here](http://cmcqueen1975.bitbucket.org/htmlFloatingTableHeader/tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take one UITableView and subclass the UITableViewCell class. This will allow you to create your own styling. So you can display multiple column next to each other. Each UITableViewCell will represent a row of your data. This will work beautifully and easy. I have no idea if you could zoom in on your UITableView.

Comment: I was planning on subclassing UITableViewCell to get the look I wanted, but my problem is the columns. If I make each cell a complete row, the data for each column has to run for the same amount of time. The main problem is the multiple columns, I could have an event for stage A run three hours, but on stage b during that time, I could have three separate hour events. The single cell would have to have multiple heights, and that isn't possible.

Comment: @BrandonMcq been there, got the tshirt :D ... to solve such problem you will not be able to use a UITableView. I would strongly suggest using a regular UIScrollView instead. Using multiple UITableViews (displayed side by side) might once again be a showstopper once one event is covering multiple stages (at least that was what prevented me from doing so for the App I had to build).